# Having trouble storing data in class constructors, learning OOP

Tags: java, oop

Here is the assignment I"m supposed to complete:

Write a program that models an employee. An employee has an employee number, a name, an address, and a hire date. A name consists of a first name and a last name. An address consists of a street, a city, a state (2 characters), and a 5-digit zip code. A date consists of an integer month, day and year.

Use an Employee class, a Name class, an Address class, and a Date class in your solution.

Your program should prompt the user to enter data for several employees and then display that data. The number of employees to store data for shall be entered from the command line.

What I'm confused about is how to use all the different classes for storing info.

Here is my code (sorry this post is so dang long)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class unitTenDemo
    {
public static void main ( String [ ] args )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
    System.out.print ( "Enter the number of employees" );
    System.out.println ( "\t" );
    int employees = input.nextInt ( );

    for (  int count = 0; count < employees; count ++ )
    {
        System.out.print ( "Enter the employees' numbers" );

        int employeeNumber = input.nextInt ( );
        System.out.println ( );
        System.out.println ( "The number is " +employeeNumber );    
        System.out.println ( );
    }
        }
    }
```

//that was the actual output code

//here's the constructor that I'm stuck on

```
    public class unitTen
{
int employeeNumber;

public int Employee ( int empNum )
{
    employeeNumber = empNum;
}

string employeeName;

public void Name ( string empName )
{
    employeeName = empName;
}

string street;
string city;
string state;
int zipCode;



}
```

Comment: Please either show code and actual problem OR ask your teacher for clarifications. It is hard to know what you supposed to use by this point to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put everything into the constructor. It's okay to write a constructor that builds an object that is not fully initialized. You can organize your program as follows:

1. Find out how many `Employee` objects there will be (user input)
2. Create an array of `Employee` objects of the appropriate length
3. For each element of the array, assign a new `Employee` to that element
4. For each element of the array, prompt the user for each piece of data needed to properly initialize the `Employee`.

The last step (which deals with only one `Employee` at a time) will break down into a lot of details, since each `Employee` object has a lot of information. Just go through all the elements systematically.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This code won't compile at all. Yopu have declaired int as return type and not returning anything from the method.

```
 public int Employee ( int empNum )
 {
      employeeNumber = empNum;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer pointed to by @Ted , you should modify your Employee class accordingly and then invoke the constructors as you please.

```
public class Employee // you should change the name of class to Employee
{
int employeeNumber;

public Employee(){}; // default constructor to create empty Employee objects
public Employee ( int empNum ) // constructor cannot have any return type
{
    employeeNumber = empNum;
}

string employeeName;

public Employee( string empName, int empNum ) // you can create multiple constructors with different parameters.
{
    employeeName = empName;
    employeeNumber = empNum;
}

string street;
string city;
string state;
int zipCode;

// you can create getters and setters for these fields

}
```